# jQuery UI datepicker not selecting the correct month in 1.12.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

When loading jQuery 3.1.1 and jQuery UI 1.12.1 (both production versions) the datepicker forward and back arrows do not take you to the proper months when numberOfMonths is greater than 1 and showCurrentAtPos is greater than 0.

The HTML is:

```
<input type=text id=selector />
```

The javaScript code to create the datepicker is very basic:

```
jQuery('#selector').datepicker({
 stepMonths: 1,
 numberOfMonths: 2,
 showCurrentAtPos: 1,
 dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
 showOtherMonths: true,
 selectOtherMonths: true,
 showButtonPanel: true
});
```

**Here is an example of the broken behavior:**

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cersos/0sf1kn3y/)

To get it to work properly, I had to load the GIT version 1.12.0-pre

**Here is an example of it working as it should:**

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cersos/sg4p0407/)

Any suggestions?  I'd prefer to use the production version of jQuery UI, but in this case, that isn't working.

[jQuery UI Bug Ticket](https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/15118#ticket)

Someone beat me to it, my bug ticket was a duplicate.

The (currently) open ticket is: [jQuery UI Bug Ticket](https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/15102)

Comment: Post at https://bugs.jqueryui.com ?

Comment: @Will P Tested in FF and IE11, no Chrome to test with.  Are you sure in the broken example, when you click the left arrow to go to the previous month, it actually goes backwards?

Comment: Appears this bug is closed. Did you get an answer? If so many include it as an answer here and close the post.